# Populate second select-dropdown based on choice of first select-dropdown angular 2 + ng2-dropdown-treeview

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using the ng2-dropdown-treeview plugin to populate a dropdown. However, I needed that after selecting a checkbox, the second dropdown was populated with the result of the first one. I have this object:

```
    Model: {
    Instituicoes: [
        {
            InstituicaoId: 1,
            Nome: "Hospital das Clinicas"
        },
        {
            InstituicaoId: 2,
            Nome: "Hospital das Clinicas 3"
        }
    ],
    Unidades: [
        {
            InstituicaoId: 1,
            Id: 2,
            Nome: "ICESP"
        },
        {
            InstituicaoId: 1,
            Id: 3,
            Nome: "ICESP 2"
        },
        {
            InstituicaoId: 2,
            Id: 4,
            Nome: "ICESP 3"
        },
        {
            InstituicaoId: 2,
            Id: 5,
            Nome: "ICESP 4"
        }
    ],
    Setores: [
        {
            UnidadeId: 2,
            Id: 3,
            Nome: "Ambulatorio"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 3,
            Id: 4,
            Nome: "Ambulatorio 2"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 4,
            Id: 5,
            Nome: "Ambulatorio 3"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 5,
            Id: 6,
            Nome: "Ambulatorio 4"
        }
    ],
    Departamentos: [
        {
            SetorId: 3,
            Id: 4,
            Nome: "Sala de Gesso"
        },
        {
            SetorId: 4,
            Id: 5,
            Nome: "Sala de Gesso 2"
        },
        {
            SetorId: 5,
            Id: 4,
            Nome: "Sala de Gesso 3"
        },
        {
            SetorId: 6,
            Id: 5,
            Nome: "Sala de Gesso 4"
        }
    ],
    Profissoes: [
        {
            UnidadeId: 2,
            Id: 5,
            Nome: "Médico"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 3,
            Id: 6,
            Nome: "Médico 2"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 2,
            Id: 5,
            Nome: "Biologo"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 3,
            Id: 6,
            Nome: "Biologo 2"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 4,
            Id: 5,
            Nome: "Médico"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 5,
            Id: 6,
            Nome: "Médico 2"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 4,
            Id: 5,
            Nome: "Biologo"
        },
        {
            UnidadeId: 5,
            Id: 6,
            Nome: "Biologo 2"
        }
    ],
    Especialidades: [
        {
            ProfissaoId: 5,
            Id: 6,
            Nome: "Ortopedia"
        },
        {
            ProfissaoId: 6,
            Id: 6,
            Nome: "Bactéria"
        }
    ],
    contratos: [
        {
            Id: 7,
            Nome: "CLT"
        },
        {
            Id: 8,
            Nome: "PJ"
        }
    ]
},
```

Institutions is the first dropdown I carry. What I need is that when Institutions 1 were marked, a filter was made in the Units array and all items with Institution 1 equal 1 were loaded in another combo. If Institutional 1 and 2 were marked, in the second combo would be loaded all items with InstituicaoId 1 and 2 were loaded.

I tried in many ways, but without success

Comment: guess you are looking for something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/ywkAlWM4NimtNvhqx917)

Comment: More or less
I need that while selecting in the first combo, go populating the second with the results